# Polymorphic categories using has_through in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I am just learning Rails, and I am having trouble assigning styles (categories) to events and user profiles. Styles are types of yoga, set up as polymorphic so I can have events, teachers, or fans of that style.

On the event form, the fields render but do not save to the database. I am trying to use the collection_select helper, with multiple selections possible. The form submits and creates the event, but nothing is saved to the "stylings" table. Is this the right way to set up polymorphic associations?

**Style.rb**

```
 has_many :stylings, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :events, :through => :stylings, :source => :styleable, :source_type => 'Event'
 has_many :profiles, :through => :stylings, :source => :styleable, :source_type => 'Profile'
 has_many :users, :through => :stylings, :source => :styleable, :source_type => 'User'
```

**Styling.rb**

```
 belongs_to :styleable, :polymorphic => true
 belongs_to :style
```

**Event.rb**

```
 has_many :stylings, :as => :styleable, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :styles, through: :stylings
```

**Profile.rb**

```
 has_many :stylings, :as => :styleable, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :styles, through: :stylings
```

**events/_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= f.label :stylings, :value => 'Styles', class: 'o-label--quiet', :required => true %>
 <%= collection_select(:event, :stylings, Style.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=> 'Select style(s)'}, {:multiple => true, :class=>'o-input--quiet js-styles'}) %>
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  @locations = Location.all
  @teachers = Profile.all
  @styles = Style.all
end

def create
  @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  @event.length = @event.end_time - @event.start_time
  @event.location_id = @event.location.id
  if @event.save
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    render 'new'
  end    
end

def edit
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @locations = Location.all
  @users = User.all
  @teachers = Profile.all
  @styles = Style.all
end

def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @locations = Location.all
  @users = User.all
  @teachers = Profile.all
  @styles = Style.all
  if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to event_path(@event)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private 

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :image, :description, :start_date, :end_date, :start_time, :end_time, :all_day, :repeat, :category, :length, :link, :location_id, :user_id, :stylings => [])
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "stylings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "style_id"
  t.integer  "styleable_id"
  t.string   "styleable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end
```

Comment: Check the logs (in development, `log/development.log`). Do they show the correct parameters passed? Do they show any parameters filtered out by strong params? Any validation errors? Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for : stylings` in your `Event` model? My hunch is your `event_params` also needs to change `:stylings => []` to `:stylings => [:id]`.

Comment: Ah, they say "unpermitted parameter: stylings"

Comment: Adding both those (`accepts_nested_attributes_for :stylings` and `:stylings => [:id]`) yields `NoMethodError in EventsController#create
undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` — removed the :id again and I'm back to the previous state, log says `"event"=>{"name"=>"Accepting Parameters", "category"=>"certification", "stylings"=>"2" ...` but also still `Unpermitted parameter: stylings`